# Split text with string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, linq

i have a text like.
  on day.Momnday vhfjj j gjhgjh ghghjg hjgh jghj gug    on day.tuesday bhjgghkg hjkhjkg jkghkj    on day.wednesday ghjgjh jghhgihi juhihi hji    on day.Friday jkhkj hjkhk j hjkh kj

now i want this text to store into array like 
on day.monday remianing text
on day.tuesday remaning text and so on.
 i tried

```
MyText.Split(new string[] { "on day." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Regex.Split(MyText, "on day.");
```

but both return only 1 result.text can contain whitespaces more than once, only idea we have to make sentance is starting sentance with "on day."

Comment: What doesn't work?  your code seems to work

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: dont know, it returns only 1 item in array in which it consist whole text

Comment: I've just tried it, and both return an array with 5 items

Comment: in actual i have uneven whitespaces before every on  day.

Comment: It doen't matter. But if you post one scenario and try your code on another, then we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide what your `MyText` might look like and what your expected result is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to keep the `"on day."` *separator* you may use:

```
        string MyText = "on day.Momnday vhfjj j gjhgjh ghghjg hjgh jghj gug on day.tuesday bhjgghkg hjkhjkg jkghkj on day.wednesday ghjgjh jghhgihi juhihi hji on day.Friday jkhkj hjkhk j hjkh kj";
        MyText=MyText.Replace("on day.", "on day|on day.");
        string[] days = MyText.Split(new string[] { "on day|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Your code is splitting assuming "on day." separator so the resulting array elements will not have that separator. My code first substitutes all "on day." occurrences with "on day|on day." and then do the splitting on "on day|" so that the "on day." part stays in array elements

Answer (score 2):

As @DisplayName noticed, `Split` method for .NET Framework doesn't have overload accepting `string` parameter as separator. It exists only in .NET Core. So, there will be two solutions:

```
string input = @"on day.Monday vhfjj ... hji on day.Friday jkhkj hjkhk j hjkh kj";
```

#### .NET Core

```
string[] x = input
             .Split("on day.", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(z => "on day." + z)
             .ToArray();
```

#### .NET Framework

```
string[] x = Regex
             .Split(input, "on day.")
             .Select(z => "on day." + z)
             .Skip(1) //Emulation of StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: @DisplayName [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-2.1)